# barplot using ggplot2 is not working with error bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a simple barplot on R using ggplot2 but I am having trouble. The y axis numbers are all messed up and the error bars are also not showing up correctly. Below is my code and this is a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q2llePNrwnmSSvG7knQhJfS78YWVWAnQ/view?usp=sharing) to my data file. Thanks!

```
#load data and view dataset
 crop.data1 <- read.csv("barleystarch1.csv", header = TRUE,stringsAsFactors = T)
 summary(crop.data1)
 crop.data1$locyear = as.factor(paste(crop.data1$location,"_",crop.data1$year,sep=''))
 View(crop.data1)
 str(crop.data1)

#barplot with error bars
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(crop.data1) +
geom_bar( aes(x=locyear, y=adry), stat="identity", fill="grey", alpha=0.5) +
geom_pointrange( aes(x=locyear, y=adry, ymin=adry-sd, ymax=adry+sd), colour="orange", 
alpha=0.95, size=0.5)+
theme_classic()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have several rows for each `locyear` (one for each `genotype`). Currently, the values for `adry` are stacking on top of each other. You either need a separate plot for each genotype, or use `genotype` for the fill aesthetic and dodge the bars at each `locyear`, or summarize the different genotypes yourself for plotting.

Here's the third option, which is closest to the plot you seemed to want:

```r
crop.data1 <- read.csv("barleystarch1.csv", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
crop.data1$locyear = as.factor(paste(crop.data1$location, "_", 
                                     crop.data1$year, sep = ''))

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

crop.data1 %>%
  group_by(locyear) %>%
  summarize(se = sd(adry, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(n()),
            adry = mean(adry, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(locyear, adry)) +
  geom_col(fill = "gray", alpha = 0.5, position = "dodge") +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = adry - se, ymax = adry + se), 
                   alpha = 0.95, size = 0.5, color = "orange",
                  position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Note though that "dynamite stick" plots like this are generally considered a poor way of showing summarized data. A boxplot, dotplot or violin plot might be better.